# Closure of uncountable union of closed sets has dense interior?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

Let $\langle A_i\rangle_{i\in I}$, $I$ uncountable, be a collection of subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$ each of which is the closure of its (non-empty) interior.

Can we infer that the interior of the set $A :=\mathrm{cl}(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i)$ is dense in $A$? In other words, is $A$ the closure of its interior?

(In the above, the closure $\mathrm{cl}(B)$ of a set $B\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ is taken w.r.t. the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}^d$.)

Comment: Singletons are Jordan measurable. That gives you lots of counterexamples. To avoid that, maybe you should require that the $A_i$ are the closures of their interior.

Comment: @DanielFischer : Thanks for your comment!

Comment: Depends on what "support of a probability density" means. If it's the support of a probability measure, then assuming $A_i$ to be the closure of its interior is much more restrictive, since all closed sets of Lebesgue measure $0$ are Jordan measurable, and all closed sets are he support of a probability measure. But if it's "support of a function that is the density with respect to the Lebesgue measure of a probability measure", then it's less of a restriction (can't say off-hand how much).

Comment: Many thanks, @DanielFischer -- the latter is what I'm interested in.

Comment: Just saying, regardless of how much of an additional restriction that condition is, it is necessary to have the conclusion. For, given an $A_{i_0}$ (that isn't dense) we can always take all the other $A_i$ at a positive distance from $A_{i_0}$.

Comment: I removed some tags. how is real analysis and measure theory tag appropriate(some context as to why)?

Comment: Thanks for editing, @PaulPlummer. In the original assertion, the $A_i$ were supposed to be Jordan-measurable, so adding measure theory seemed appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is true. Let $a\in A$, so that there is a sequence $a_n$ of points in $\bigcup A_i$ such that $(a_n)$ approaches $a$ (as $n$ goes to infinity). Since each $A_i$ is the closure of its interior, and since the interior of $A_i$ is contained in $A$ for every $i$, we can find, for every $n\in \Bbb{N}$, a point $(b_{n,m})_{m=1}^\infty$ of distance at most $\frac{1}{m}$ from $a_n$. It is easy to see that $b_{n,n}$ approaches $a$ as $n$ goes to infinity, so $a$ is in the closure of the interior of $A$. The other inclusion is trivial, so $A$ equals the closure of its interior.